# what is the meaning of warning says" tensorflow using weight layer instead of variable layer"

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I work with transfer-learning, I use pretrained-model as feature-extraction, then add dense_layer, but the layer I add is Dense_Flipout_layer(this layer from tensor_probability-_library).
after apply (model.compile) then(model.fit), it shows this message, what does it mean? have I change layer or paramter?

> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/layers/util.py:98:
> UserWarning: `layer.add_variable` is deprecated and will be removed in
> a future version. Please use the `layer.add_weight()` method instead.
> loc = add_variable_fn(
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/layers/util.py:108:
> UserWarning: `layer.add_variable` is deprecated and will be removed in
> a future version. Please use the `layer.add_weight()` method instead.
> untransformed_scale = add_variable_fn(

Comment: Looks like it's coming from `tensorflow_probability` itself. I don't think you can do much besides telling the maintainers about this.